# FileVault will not finish and cannot turn FileVault Off

Tags: high-sierra, filevault

I have a MacBook Air and when I tried to install High Sierra, I was unable to do so because I received the message that I needed to turn FileVault off.  When I went to FileVault it showed that it is decrypting but does not show the time remaining.  I let it run for 8 days with no change.  I have tried turning it off in Terminal but I get the message that FileVault is off.  I have tried rebooting in recovery made but this did not help.

Suggestions?